# what is this minikube tunnel starting problem. Is my minikube tunnel is not working that why I am not able to access my pod externally

Tags: kubernetes

I was trying to run minikube service

I am expecting to open my service on default browser. I want to have solution of Kubernetes tunnel problem. Please help me with that I am trying to solve this problem for last 2 days tried ever possible documentation tried chat gpt, bard, bind and rix but I am dispointed now that no one solved my problem.

Comment: you should provide more details on what you’re trying to do with minikube, the error you’re encountering, and what you need help with. Adding screenshots and your configuration files will also help people better understand the issue